# Java - Find a sequence of pixels

Tags: java

Was just wondering how you would be able to check each pixel, from top of your screen to bottom (or just a 500x500 rectangle) for a pattern of pixels in it. Example look through all the pixels, and see if there is 20 red pixels in a row (Search the screen for a red box).
Sorry for the terrible description, let me know and ill try to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called [Template Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) in the Image Processing community, you should first check this.

For the implementation part, you can access the pixels of `BufferedImage` (using `getRGB/getRGBs` methods), or even better you can use JAI or JavaCV if you want to do anything serious.